# How to override peek method in Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My application has scenario of having users (both active and deleted ) in the users.js model.

But earlier it was only having active users. so, if I add deleted to the same model then it would affect other places where I don't need to the deleted users and which lead me to make changes in many places.

### so, I wanted to override peekAll in ember-data to get required data from user model.

**something like this**:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    peek: () {
        //...
    }
});
```

But there is no such thing in ember-data docs.

**Is there any way to override peekAll method ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't override peekAll method. I would recommend to use `filterBy` using `isDeleted` flag.

```
let users = this.get('store').peekAll('user');
activeUsers = users.filterBy('isDeleted',false);
```

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isDeleted

EDIT: You can map the server returned `isDeleted` key to some other name in model. 
For this you need to create serializer for `user` model, by running `ember g serializer user`

`app/models/user.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  isDeletedFlag: DS.attr('string')
});
```

`app/serializers/user.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  attrs: {
    isDeletedFlag: 'isDeleted'
  }
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_attribute-names

EDIT: This twiddle is only for you. I will not recommend this for others, since this might create issue in future upgrade.
[Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/b0ed89431a42d10a1cd781bc5a33ca63?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C) which overwrite peekAll method and does what you required

Comment: I know this but this will lead to many changes as I am working on a heavy application.

Comment: Then you are about to override internal private method of  store.js. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.11.0/addon/-private/system/store.js#L1607 . I would say this is not correct approach. IMO

Comment: From backend, I am getting one flag called isDeleted true which is the part of the model which signifies that the user is deleted.
but the ember model property called isDeleted will delete the data from a local model. which I don't want.

Comment: Updated: The flag I am getting from the backend is **deleted: true**. but from this discussion, I can find that only way to handle this situation is to filter the data according to the flag delete.
Even overriding peekAll is not working.

Comment: Updated my answer with what you exactly need, though I will recommend to implement in all the required places or create serializer for user model and implement `normailzeResponse` method where you can delete the payload which comes with `delete: true`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend what kumkanillam said.. However to answer your question you CAN override peekAll method by creating an adapter for your users model

adapters/users.js

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
   peekAll: () {
       //...
   }
});
```